# How to predict multiple svm models in R?

Tags: r, svm

I have train and test images separately. I want to predict the SVM models in an iterative way. After creating models if i predict the result, i can see only the last predicted value rather than all the predicted values for n number of models. I would like to know how to automate the process of creating n SVM models and predict all the values.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post some of your code so that it is easier to understand your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your problem is a "multi-class" problem, you can directly apply SVM function provided by e1071 for training your data which are properly labelled.

If your problem is a "multi-instance" problem, you can train multiple SVM models by giving them different names. For automating iterations, you can play the trick using paste(). Something like

```
for (n in 1:itr) {
  svm.model <- svm(label~., data)
  assign(paste("svm.model", n, sep = "."), svm.model)
}
```

You will get svm.model.1, svm.model.2, ... for multiple SVM models, respectively.